# Partition size inconsistent

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, ntfs

I have a MAC that had Windows installed (using Bootcamp) with a damaged HDD (15 S.M.A.R.T. Errors).
If i attach the disk to a linux machine it reports the following data:

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 1953525168s
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start        End          Size        File system  Name                  Flags
 1      40s          409639s      409600s     fat32        EFI system partition  boot, esp
 2      409640s      586498047s   586088408s  hfs+         Customer
 3      586498048s   587767583s   1269536s    hfs+         Recovery HD
 4      1565007872s  1953521663s  388513792s  ntfs         Basic data partition  msftdata
```

So far everything seems right, apart from the fact that the NTFS partition is very small and there are 977.240.289 sectors unused (which makes no sense to do so). If i try to mount it:

```
root@werkstatt-debian-lenovo:~# mount /dev/sdc4 /mnt/
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc4,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

Then I opened it in Windows, which showed me a full 651,24 GB Partition.

[image]

The data on the partition, as detected using Windows seems fine, apart from the fact that Windows is not booting, but that's another story.

Using a RAW disk editor on windows reveals the following structure:

The raw (protective) MBR:

[image]

The raw GPT:

[image]

What's confusing me is the fact, that windows acts like it's GPT, but the raw disk editor and Linux say it's MBR. Could the MBR be wrong, but the GPT right?

Comment: Linux also reports it as a gpt disk (third line). It's odd that the MBR actually has partition data. As it's a difference of several hundred GBs check what the physical size of the disk should be.

Comment: "Hybrid MBR" (where the GPT and the MBR have conflicting partition data) is not uncommon; it's sometimes intentionally done to work around buggy firmware that doesn't understand the protective MBR. Of course it's a hack best avoided...

Comment: @Seth The physical size of the disk is 1000 Gb, it's a ST3100528AS

Comment: @grawity Is it possible that bootcamp (because it's Windows on a Mac) did that?

Comment: Boot Camp? I don't know, but I also wouldn't be surprised if it did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The drive is using a hybrid partition scheme. This means Windows uses the values in the Master Boot Record (MBR) table. OS X (macOS) uses the values in the GUID Partition Table (GPT). Most of the time, Linux also uses the values in the GPT. Hybrid partitioning usally results in the common values stored in the 2nd, 3rd and 4th entries of the MBR partition table are repeated in the GPT. By common, I mean the values representing the type of partition and where the partition resides.

OS X (macOS) is aware there are values stored in both the MBR partition table and the GPT. However, Windows only knows of the MBR partition table.

Your question is repeated below:

> What's confusing me is the fact, that windows acts like it's GPT, but the raw disk editor and Linux say it's MBR. Could the MBR be wrong, but the GPT right?

No, you are wrong. Windows acts like it is MBR and Linux says it is GPT. In fact there are two partition tables: the MBR partition table and a GPT.

The 2nd and 3rd entries in both the MBR partition table and GPT are the same (as they should be), but the 4th entry for Windows is different. If the MBR partition table entry is correct, then linux is reading the wrong values stored in the GPT.

The start value (First LBA) of `1565007872` sectors in the 4 entry of the GPT *probably* should be the value `587767808`, which is the start value in the MBR partition table. A suppose one could do a hex dump of the first sector of the partition to see if the NTFS header looks OK. Or, make the change and see if the partition (NTFS volume) mounts.

Comment: So how do i make it readable on Linux? Can i just remove the MBR header so that linux is forced to use GPT?

Comment: I used fdisk to delete the old partition and create a new one according to the start and end sector of the MBR in GPT as suggested. Mounting now works on both, linux and windows